# How to change text color of a css class?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am using Bootstrap.css, and there's a class named "form-control".
I am using this class to style my aspx controls. The problem is that its textbox font color is grey and I want it to be black. I have no clue about CSS. Is there a way I can change that from grey to black?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset the text color of class - 'form-control' by adding

```
.form-control {
  color:#000000;
}
```

Add this property in a separate css file and include it just below bootstrap.min.css in head tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the textboxes font color to be black, add this:

```
input[type="text"] { color: black }
```

in your CSS file.

Otherwise, create a class:

```
.black-input {
  color: black
}
```

`<input type="text" class="black-input">`

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and select the colors you want, then Compile and Download at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
.input-black {
 // this is the one can change the color of a text even if its a placeholder
 color: black;
}

<input type="text" class="input-black">
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add some code like this to your CSS file.

```
.form-control {
  color: #000;
}
```

Keep in mind that you may have some specificity declaration issues. For example, if the color is set in bootstrap.css as a child of another element, you may not be able to override the color change unless you declare it with the parent as well. For example:

```
.parent .form-control {
  color: #000;
}
```

You shouldn't be scared to learn some CSS though. It's very easy to grasp (you'll literally get the basics in less than an hour).